# Heap snapshot Selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is there any way to get Heap Snapshot from the Selenium webdriver? 
I am currently using Chrome with Chrome driver.

I understand that both Inspector and Selenium connects via the same port. 
In inspector, it provides method to take heap snapshot. 
I was thinking, this should possible via Selenium also as both work on similar way.

Thanks.

**EDITED:**
By passing the below code, I was able to get the heap snapshot.

```
import json
jsonobj=driver.execute_script(":takeHeapSnapshot")
f = filename('heap','w')
f.write(json.dumps(jsonobj))
f.close
```

But when I load in the Chrome, it gives me error: 
An error occurred when a call to method 'close' was requested

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at Object.WebInspector.HeapSnapshotLoader._parseStringsArray (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/profiler/heap_snapshot_worker/HeapSnapshotWorker.js:748:117)
>       at Object.WebInspector.HeapSnapshotLoader.close (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/profiler/heap_snapshot_worker/HeapSnapshotWorker.js:737:6)
>       at Object.WebInspector.HeapSnapshotWorkerDispatcher.dispatchMessage
>   (chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/profiler/heap_snapshot_worker/HeapSnapshotWorker.js:789:95)

I tried comparing the file with actual HeapSnapshot saved from Chrome. The tags/names seems to be present in different places but its a valid JSON file. (Verified with jsonlint).

Any body has details on how chrome-inspector->Profile requires the JSON file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the streamable json to get read it by the devtools. Smth like this:

```
{
"snapshot":{ }
,
"nodes": { }
,
"edges":[]
,
"trace_function_infos":[]
,
"trace_tree":[]
,
"samples":[]
,
"strings":[]
}
```

The Javascript example to get the idea:

```
var open = '{\n', close = '\n}\n';
var keys = [];
for (var key in json) {
    keys.push('"' + key + '":' + JSON.stringify(json[key]));
}

var str = open + keys.join('\n,\n') + close;
```

You can also take a look into the [JSONStream](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) NodeJS module for more information

The Keys order is also important. The order is: `['snapshot', 'nodes', 'edges', 'trace_function_infos', 'trace_tree', 'samples', 'strings']`